# today() function returns date with time when project converted to .net

Tags: c#, datetime, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-conversion

My application behaves differently when I work on Windows Server 2008 R2.

When I converted my PowerScript to .net project, today() 's functions returns the value as date along with time (date+time) instead of only date.

```
ldt_date = today()
```

any suggestions?

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want...

Comment: Are you saying you converted to PowerBuilder.NET or to some other .NET language?

Answer (score 2):

you can add ToString formatting

```
yourdate.ToString("d");
```

Answer (score 1):

That is normal .NET behavior.

```
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString);  //output 6/23/2012 12:00:00 AM
```

if you want date only  (6/23/2012) try:

```
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToShortDateString());  //output 6/23/2012
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET you can get the only date part of DateTime variable using [**DateTime.Date Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx)

It's like

```
 yourdate.ToString("d")
```

Example

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 6, 1, 7, 47, 0);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString());

// Get date-only portion of date, without its time.
DateTime dateOnly = date1.Date;
// Display date using short date string.
Console.WriteLine(dateOnly.ToString("d"));
```